# SSRS limit axis value

Tags: reporting-services

I want to limit the max value of the vertical axis to 100 % and not 101%.
[image: Percentage chart]
I have tried setting the axis limit to 100 but that did not help either. Changing that to 100.05% just changes the axis label but the line does not jump to the top of the chart. Is there a way to restrict the high value of the axis to a particular number?

Follow up question: I see this in ChartDataLabel. What does this mean  `=IIF(Fields!Reliability.Value >= 100, "", Fields!Reliability.Value)` ?

Comment: For the time being, I circumvented the issue by checking always include zero.

Answer (score 2):

To do what you want, while in design mode, right-click on the axis and choose Vertical Axis Properties. Set the Minimum and Maximum values to what you want.

Now, it sounds like that is something you have already tried, but didn't like the results. Another thing you can do is use the values from the data set, along with an expression, to set the min and max values for the axis. So, instead of setting the min and max values manually, you can try something like the following. This assumes the value you are charting is `Fields!Reliability.Value`.

```
Minimum: =Min(Fields!Reliability.Value)
Maximum: =Max(Fields!Reliability.Value)
```

If you want a little bit of a buffer above and below the value line, then you can add and subtract from those values like this:

```
Minimum: =Min(Fields!Reliability.Value)*0.95
Maximum: =Max(Fields!Reliability.Value)*1.05
```

Adjust these as desired.

To answer your follow up question about the ChartDataLabel.

```
=IIF(Fields!Reliability.Value >= 100, "", Fields!Reliability.Value)
```

This expression sets the ChartDataLabel to an empty string if the `Fields!Reliability.Value` from the data set is greater than 100, otherwise it uses whatever value is in `Fields!Reliability.Value`.

Hope this helps you out.